# Two observableArrays don't work together in the same page with a nested viewModel

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have this viewModel:

### ViewModel

```
var sitesTableModel = [
{
   nameCol: "nameCol-1",
   pagesCol: "editorCol-1",
},
{
    nameCol: "nameCol-2",
    pagesCol: "pagesCol-2",
}];

var pagesTableModel = [
{
   lastCol: "lastCol-1",
   editedCol: "editedCol-1",
},
{
    lastCol: "lastCol-2",
    editedCol: "editedCol-2",
}];


var viewModel = {
    sitesTable: ko.observableArray(sitesTableModel),
    pagesTable: ko.observableArray(pagesTableModel),
};
```

then I call a webservice in this way:

### Ajax Call

```
ajaxService = (function () {
var ajaxGetJson = function (method, request, callback, service) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:2880/Whatever.svc/Method",
        type: "GET",
        data: request,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result, statusMsg, status)
        {
            callback(result, statusMsg, status, request);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed 
    }).always(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel); 
        });
}
return {
    ajaxGetJson: ajaxGetJson,
};
})();
```

and map the result in this way:

### Mapping

```
function ModelTableSitesMapper(result, statusMsg, status, request) {

    var itemRow = [];

    //sitesTableModel
    result.forEach(function (entry) {
        itemRow.push({
            nameCol: entry.Title,
            pagesCol: entry.Pages,
        })
    });

    viewModel.sitesTable = ko.observableArray(itemRow);

};
```

And the same for the other array.

Now here is my data binding:

### Data Binding

```
    <table id="tableDocs">  
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: documentsTable" >
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: nameCol">Simon Werner Hansen</td>
            <td data-bind="text: pagesCol">swh002</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <table id="tableSites">  
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: documentsTable" >
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: lastCol">Simon Werner Hansen</td>
            <td data-bind="text: editedCol">swh002</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

If I comment one of the two the other work fine, but if they are together on the same page the table is just empty, no errors or nothing.

Aomething to do with the context of the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I was applying the binding ko.applyBinding on the **.always** function of the ajax call, but because I was calling the service twice for 2 different reasons the binding was applied **TWICE**.

I donøt know why but for some reason that prevented the 2 different observableArrays to work together in the same model. So this is a solution but it does not explain why this happended.

I just moved the binding outside the function just after I create my model.

Comment: I'm glad you found the issue, Maurizio.

Answer (score 1):

I notice in your mapping code you're doing

```
viewModel.sitesTable = ko.observableArray(itemRow);
```

and I'm wondering if you want

```
viewModel.sitesTable(itemRow);
```

---

Once you've created your knockout observable or observableArray during initialization, you'll want to be careful not to overwrite those with another new observableArray, particularly once you've called ko.applyBindings().

I think this is best shown with an example...

```
//Initialize my view model
var myOriginalObservable = ko.observableArray([initialValue]);

var viewModel = {
    modelProperty : myOriginalObservable
}

//Call applyBindings
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

//In some other function, I reset viewModel.modelPropert = ko.observableArray()
var myNewObservable = ko.observableArray([newValue]);

viewModel.modelProperty = myNewObservable;
```

After the call to applyBindings, some other operation sets my viewModel's property *to a new observable* instead of just changing the values in the existing observable.  The observable that I created in initialization (myOriginalObservable) is still there, and my UI is still bound to it, but I've lost my reference to it when I changed the object that viewModel.modelProperty pointed to (myNewObservable).

I think this may be the issue you're running in to.

Comment: if I do like you say at the beginning(viewModel.sitesTable(itemRow);) it just does not work for me, I know it's the right way, but ig I use it nothing is shown in my table.

Comment: then Iøve done what you say in the second part of your post, but the code just work in the same way as my code, it makes no difference.